# Getting an error using MongoDB aggregate $sample operation. -- MongoError: $sample stage could not find a non-duplicate document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

`MongoError: $sample stage could not find a non-duplicate document after 100 while using a random cursor. This is likely a sporadic failure, please try again.`

Using MongoDB version 3.2.8 and just upgraded to 3.2.10.

I'm following [the example set forth by the MongoDB documentation.](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/). There is very little documentation. The only thing I can find doing a search is a [bug in an issue queue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-20503) which doesn't solve the problem for me.

My implementation is very simple.

```
function createBattle(done) {
    // Need to make sure that the yachts are different.
    async.doWhilst(
        function(callback) {
            Yacht.aggregate(
                {
                    $sample: { size: 2 }
                },
                function (err, results) {
                    console.log(err.toString());
                    if (err) return callback(err);
                    callback(null, results);
                }
            )
        },
        function(results) {
            return results.length !== 2 || _.isEqual(results[0]._id, results[1]._id);
        },
        function(err, results) {
            if (err) return done(err);
            done(null, results);
        }
    )
}
```

I'm not sure what is going on. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Mongoose. It is in development. My guess is that something occurred when I changed the schema of the document. It works with the test mock data after creating 100000 fake documents or just 10 documents. So I decided to try a fresh start on the collection on the development instance of the database. Regardless, I exported the collection into a clean JSON file. I deleted the collection in the database. Then I imported the JSON dump. It works fine.

It's a bug.

This is probably the last straw with MongoDB for me. I'll probably go back to SQL, use Redis, and try PostGRES.

Comment: fwiw - not an issue with mongoose. appears to be with wiredtiger and still present in mongodb 4.0.4. see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-29446 . See https://github.com/wiredtiger/wiredtiger/pull/2194/files for possible code-comment explanation of "why"